# How to validate the UI level performance testing for different browser?

Tags: performance-testing

How to validate the UI level performance testing for different browser?

I need to find the page loading time of my web application, when i check the performance with API its fast when we compare the timing with actual page loading time. And i need to validate the performance with each browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) browser automation framework which is capable of kicking off and controlling [different browsers](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.jsp#selenium-webdriver) such as:

- Google Chrome
- Internet Explorer 7, 8, 9, 10, and 11 on appropriate combinations of Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1. As of April 15 2014, IE 6 is no longer supported. The driver supports running 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the browser where applicable
- Firefox: latest ESR, previous ESR, current release, one previous release
- Safari
- Opera
- HtmlUnit
- phantomjs
- Android (with Selendroid or appium)
- iOS (with ios-driver or appium)

So you can code your scenario in any [supported programming language](http://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp) like:

- C#
- Haskell
- Java
- JavaScript
- Objective-C
- Perl
- PHP
- Python
- R
- Ruby

and measure the time required for each step for each browser, even in [parallel](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp).

---

If you need to add some performance testing flavor to your timings collection you can consider [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) multiprotocol load testing tool which can be integrated with Selenium via [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler)

Comment: Did we have any tools to validate.

Answer (score 0):

This is is a functional question which can be solved with the use of DevTools inside of each browser or by the use of a functional automation tool which will operate your browser and which includes a timing API for reporting.

Comment: What you mean by DevTools? will please provide me any specific tool names.

Comment: The built in dev tools for your browser.  Or, you can use your choice of GUI + API performance testing tool from IBM, Microfocus, Neotys, Open source items such as Blazemeter, Tricentis, OctoPerf.   Ultimately this is a functional question as you are looking at complexity for a known constant by browser and not by load.  You could also look at it by number of tabs open or number of toolbars installed.

Comment: Thanks @james Pulley